# Adding an iPhone app binary to my current ipad app

Tags: iphone, ipad

I gave an app in the app store got ipad. I also made a app for the iPhone now. 
What you guys suggest should I create a new app for the iPhone or is there way to add my iPhone binary to my current ipad app?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to include the iPad and iPhone binary together.  If you want to put them together, you'll need to create a [universal application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW2).  You will have checks at run time that will determine whether or not your app is running on an iPad or iPhone, this will determine which set of ViewControllers your app will display.

There is a lot of information out there on creating universal apps.